# From the two same lines, one is generating an error relative to FutureOrNull

Tags: dart, future

Thos are the two  function from the same class I wrote: The first has the error:

> A value of type 'Future<String?>' can't be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr'.

while the second is OK and I don't understand why.

Can you tell me please?

```dart
  /// Creates or update the User collection
  Future<String?> _createOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    final email = user.email;
    final nameFromEmail =
        email!.substring(0, email.indexOf('@')).replaceAll(".", " ").trim();

    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      'id': user.uid,
      'screenName': '',
      'displayName': user.displayName ?? nameFromEmail,
      'photoUrl': user.photoURL,
      'bio': '',
      'darkMode': false,
      'email': user.email,
    }).then((_) {
      debugPrint("User ${user.displayName} is created");
      return null;
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return Future<String?>.error(e);  // <<<<< Error here: A value of type 'Future<String?>' can't be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr<Null>'.
    });
  }

  Future<String?> _authUser(BuildContext context, LoginData data) {
    debugPrint('Name: ${data.name}, Password: ${data.password}');

    return auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: data.name, password: data.password)
        .then((credential) {
      try {
        final user = credential.user;

        if (user == null) {
          return 'Password does not match';
        } else {
          _createOrUpdateUser(user);

          // == Tell the app we just signed in
          Provider.of<StateModel>(context, listen: false).signedIn = user;
          return null;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return 'User not exists';
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        debugPrint('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        debugPrint('The account already exists for that email.');
      } else {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }

      return Future<String?>.error(e);    // <<<<< No problem here
    });
  }
```

Comment: Look at what is returned in each `.then` prior to the `.catchError`. In the first you return `null`, and in the second you return a `String?`. Your `.catchError` should return the same type as the `Future` it is being called on. One thing you can do is call `.then<String?>` to ensure that you get a `Future<String?>` instead of `Future<Null>`.

Comment: Oh my! You're right, thanks a lot for pointing this out to me.